MapKit и Flutter - не подгружаются тайлы
Добавил в проект пакет yandex_maps_mapkit, и добавил контрол на виджет согласно документации Яндекса (ссылка).
При запуске в эмуляторе контрол YandexMap отображается, даже виден логотип в правом-нижнем углу, но не грузится сама карта:

Я также локально запустил тестовые примеры приложения от Яндекса - в них карта отображается корректно.
Между моим проектом, и этими тестовыми проектами не вижу разницы в настройках. Есть одно отличие - тестовые примеры запрашивают разрешение на использование данных геолокации, но разве это влияет на загрузку карты?
Секция разрешений в android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml одинакова в моём и в тестовых проектах:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


Код Flutter также взят из документации - инициализация в точке входа, и создание контрола на виджете:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
  await init.initMapkit(
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
  );
            
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
  
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
  
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  MapWindow? _mapWindow;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: YandexMap(onMapCreated: (mapWindow) => _mapWindow = mapWindow)
      )
    );
  }
}

Использую пакет yandex_maps_mapkit версии 4.8.2-beta
IDE Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1
Flutter 3.24.4

Пожалуйста, пришлите нам минимальный воспроизводимый пример вашей ситуации. Вы можете выложить его проектом на GitHub, прикрепить в архиве или загрузить на Яндекс Диск и указать ссылку.

Кстати я пробовал тоже подключить этот виджет, у меня так же получилось как у вас. Думаю это связано с тем, что мы грузим на Эмуляторе  без доступа к интернету.

@YaSupport спасибо за ответ. Не было времени раньше вернуться к проекту.
Уже собирался сделать для вас минимальный пример для воспроизведения ошибки, но ниже дали варинат, и решил сперва попробовать его. В результате всё заработало.

@ЕвгенийЛи на эмуляторе есть интернет, иначе бы карта не отобразилась на тестовом проекте Яндекса))
Ну и я сам открывал Хром в эмуляторе и проверял доступ к интернету.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit/init.dart' as init;
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit/mapkit.dart';
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit/mapkit_factory.dart';
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit/yandex_map.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await init.initMapkit(
      apiKey: 'your key',
      locale: 'ru_RU'
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  MapWindow? _mapWindow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body:
            YandexMap(onMapCreated: (mapwindow) {
              _mapWindow = mapwindow;
              mapkit.onStart();
            })
        )
    );
  }
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

@blosser, спасибо за ответ, заработало.
Оказалось, дело в вызове mapkit.onStart(); при отображении контрола.
